# discord.py [mp3 @ 000001dc99bec540] Estimating duration from bitrate, this may be inaccurate

Tags: python, ffmpeg, mp3, discord.py, ggts

I have a problem with "[mp3 @ 000001dc99bec540] Estimating duration from bitrate, this may be inaccurate", using discord.py. Everything works (bot is speaking the text, which we tell him), but, at the end, always shows it. How can I solve it?

```
        if _command == "speak":
            try:
                await message.delete()
                try:
                    error = _message[1]
                except IndexError:
                    message = await _channel.send("Where is my text, which I have to speak?!")
                    await asyncio.sleep(3)
                    await message.delete()
                    return
                channel = message.author.voice.channel
                voice = discord.utils.get(client.voice_clients, guild=_guild)
                if voice and voice.is_connected():
                    await voice.move_to(channel)
                else:
                    voice = await channel.connect()
                tts = gTTS(text=text, lang='en')
                tts.save("pcvoice.mp3")
                voice.play(discord.FFmpegPCMAudio(executable=r"C:\ffmpeg\bin\ffmpeg.exe", source="pcvoice.mp3"))
            except discord.errors.ClientException:
                await _channel.send("Come on! I am already playing something!")
```

Comment: Sounds like an ffmpeg debug flag is on.

Comment: Well, do you know how to disable it?

Answer (score 1):

This is a perfectly normal FFmpeg debug print
A way to disable this, while probably not the best is doing

```py
discord.FFmpegPCMAudio(options = "-loglevel panic")
```

or any other loglevel FFmpeg deems acceptable.
This is generally bad because if FFmpeg is failing, you might want to know.